# R: change all variables in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this type od data frame

**Data**

```
structure(list(ID = 1:3, WEEK1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L), WEEK2 = c(2L, 
2L, 3L), WEEK3 = c(3L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

DF

ID  WEEK1    WEEK2   WEEK3
1   1        2       3
2   2        2       3
3   1        3       2
```

I would like to change variables like this:

```
DF

ID  WEEK1    WEEK2   WEEK3
1   A        B       C
2   B        B       C
3   A        C       B
```

I have tried

```
DF %>% mutate_all (1="A", 2="B", 3="C")
```

Comment: TRy `DF[-1] <- LETTERS[as.matrix(DF[-1])]`

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("WEEK"), chartr, old = '123', new =  'ABC'))
```

Comment: Is there more common solution with selection of columns with different names?

Comment: An older syntax  would be mutate_at(c("WEEK1", "WEEK2", "WEEK3"), chartr, old = '123', new =  'ABC')